# VBA Multiple value setting

Tags: vba, excel, colors, userform

Having some issues with user form and setting the initial values, what I'm trying to run is the following:

```
Sub colorme()
For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = UserForm1.colorcodeinit.Value Then
    With cell
    .Interior.ColorIndex = UserForm1.colorcodefin.Value
    End With
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

However, when I try to run it's not registering for the initial color I'm setting, the following works just fine:

```
Sub colorme()
For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
    With cell
    .Interior.ColorIndex = UserForm1.colorcodefin.Value
    End With
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Thanks for any and all help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how your colorcodeinit control value is set, you may need to ensure the form is fully loaded and open before you try to read any values.

I'm reformatting your code to render in SO/Markdown. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code itself, it's probably just *when* the code is run that is the problem.

Note that ColorIndex may not be reliable across all Excel users.

Block 1:

```
'Your first code block
Sub colorme()
  For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = UserForm1.colorcodeinit.Value Then
      With cell
        .Interior.ColorIndex = UserForm1.colorcodefin.Value
      End With
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Block 2:

```
'Your second code block
Sub colorme()
  For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
      With cell
        .Interior.ColorIndex = UserForm1.colorcodefin.Value
      End With
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```